# Why is HTML validation not working in Electron?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I've searched for this for a while. I have an Electron (version 13.2.2, Node v14.17.3, Chrome 92) application that I want to add some validations to, in one of the simple forms I have.
The code below is part of the HTML file that is loaded in a window. The results are passed through IPC communication and everything else Electron-related works fine. Console logs don't show anything undefined or any other issue at all.
When I open the HTML file directly in Chrome, for instance, I get the required name working as advertised and also the regex pattern being applied to the input in the year field. But in my Electron window, I can still save objects without any validation being triggered. Searching on GitHub I found an issue that is somewhat similar (although I'm not facing any other issues whatsoever, this is a working app) but it mentions it's been closed as fixed (https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1043). What am I missing to get the `required` and `pattern` validations to work?

This is the HTML form:

```html
    <section>
      <form action="#" method="POST" id="add-new-pattern-form">
        <label for="pattern-name">Name:</label>
        <input id="pattern-name" type="text" name="pattern-name" required />
        <p></p>
        <div id="cover-image"></div>
        <p></p>
        <button type="button" id="open-cover-image">Add Cover Image</button>
        <p></p>
        <label for="company-name">Company:</label>
        <input id="company-name" type="text" name="company-name" />
        <p></p>
        <label for="year">Year:</label>
        <input id="year" type="text" name="year" pattern="^\d{4}$" />
        <p></p>
        <label for="notes">Notes:</label>
        <textarea id="notes" name="notes" style="resize: true"></textarea>
        <p></p>
        <div id="additional-images"></div>
        <p></p>
        <button type="button" id="add-images">Add Images</button>
        <p></p>
        <input
          id="submit-new-pattern-button"
          type="submit"
          value="Save Pattern"
        />
      </form>
    </section>
```

This is the usage in the renderer:

```js
submitNewPatternButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("addnewrenderer - click submit new pattern button");
  let pattern = createPatternObjectFromInputs();
  ipcRenderer.send("submit-new-pattern-button-clicked", pattern);
});
```

Another relevant piece of data is the window setup in the main process:

```js
const createNewWindow = (fileLocation, id) => {
  let x, y;
  const currentWindow = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();

  // When we already have a window we open a new one to the right and down of the current one
  if (currentWindow) {
    const [currentWindowX, currentWindowY] = currentWindow.getPosition();
    x = currentWindowX + 20;
    y = currentWindowY + 20;
  }

  let newWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    x,
    y,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
    show: false,
  });

  newWindow.loadFile(fileLocation);

  newWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
    newWindow.show();
  });

  // Necessary otherwise the HTML default title is always used
  newWindow.on("page-title-updated", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  newWindow.on("close", () => {
    windows.delete(id);
    newWindow = null;
  });

  windows.set(id, newWindow);
  console.log("main - finished new window creation for id: " + id);

  return newWindow;
};
```

One final note I'll add is that while refactoring code to use `preload.js` and set `contextIsolation: true` and `nodeIntegration: false` (the default values after Electron 12 and as per security best practices) I noticed that when I have an error in the page the validations work.

For instance, let's say I introduce a deliberate error in my renderer such as:

```js
const x;
x.doSomething;
```

In this case, the validations work! Obviously, nothing else does :)

Comment: It is worth specifying the version number of Electron and Chrome you tested with.  (But the issue you linked said the submit didn't work, whereas in your case it does?)  Is there anything appearing in the console log that gives a clue?

Comment: Are you using `event.preventDefault();` while handling your form? It makes the browser ignore the `required` attributes. It would be helpful to see some JavaScript code as your HTML markup looks valid and shouldn't behave differently just because it is being served in an Electron window.

Comment: @Looky1173 I do use `event.preventDefault()` to set the title of a new window, after the `page-title-updated` event. I tried removing it but doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @JoãoMartinho Try [listening for the `submit` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) fired by the form. According to the MDN docs, this should not ignore form validation.

Comment: @Looky1173 that worked! I'm now listening for the whole submit event to take place on the form `addNewPatternForm.addEventListener("submit", () => { //do my thing });` instead of listening for the button. I'm still not sure why this happens, but if you want to create an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: @JoãoMartinho Indeed, JavaScript and HTML forms can be tricky to use together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that the `submit` event fires on the  element itself, and not on any `<button>` or `<input type="submit">` inside it. However, the `SubmitEvent` which is sent to indicate the form's submit action has been triggered includes a `submitter` property, which is the button that was invoked to trigger the submit request.
>
> [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)

The form validation is tied to the `submit` event, which fires on the form element, thus listening for a click event on the submit button won't trigger it.

Instead, try listening to the `submit` event fired by the form, like so:

```js
const formElement = document.getElementById('myForm');
formElement.addEventListener('submit', () => {
    // Handle form submission
});
```